# How to automatically set an alias when bash starts up in CentOS?

Tags: linux, bash, alias

When bash terminal starts up, I want it to automatically set some aliases, but for some reason they don't work correctly.

I have a bash script called `.bash_aliases`, and in my `.bashrc` file I have the following code:

```
if [ -f .bash_aliases ]; then
        echo "bash_aliases file is here" 
        ./.bash_aliases
fi
```

in the file `.bash_aliases` I have:

```
"creating alias for baaa"
alias baaa='echo "baaa"'
```

now, when I launch the terminal, I see:

```
bash_aliases file is here
creating alias for baaa
```

But when I try the command:

```
baaa
```

I get this?

```
bash: baaa: command not found...
```

How does that make any sense?
However, when I do from the terminal,

```
[<>@<> ~]$ alias baaa='echo "baaa"'
[<>@<> ~]$ baaa
baaa
```

which is expected.  Why doesn't it work to set an alias in `.bash_aliases` file?  I made sure that the file was executable: `sudo chmod 777 .bash_aliases`.

I'm using CentOS 7.

Comment: Do you know what the `source` command does? `.` is an alias for the `source` command.

Comment: There's absolutely no need to make the file executable. (And don't **ever** use `chmod 777`, which gives write to every account on the system; this includes including anonymous accounts such as `nobody`, used for -- among other things -- sandboxing untrusted authentication code).

Comment: Allow just enough DAC permissions for files and folders. `777` is inviting trouble. See [\[ this \]](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_04.html).

Answer (score 3):

Punctuation matters. For aliases to be added, you need to *source* the script defining them, executing them in your current shell:

```
# WORKS: source file named bash_aliases in the current directory
. ./.bash_aliases       # POSIX-compliant syntax
```

...also written as...

```
# WORKS: source file named bash_aliases in the current directory
source ./.bash_aliases   # bash-only syntax
```

---

If instead you do the following:

```
# BROKEN: Run .bash_aliases as subprocess
./.bash_aliases
```

...it runs as a separate script, and the aliases are forgotten when that script exits.

---

By the way -- since sourcing a script reads it into the current shell rather than executing it as a separate program, *this means that it doesn't need file permissions to be executable*. Thus, your `.bash_aliases` need not and should not have `+x` permissions.